# Batch save symbols for each category of a layer as style in ArcGIS

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, symbology

I have a soiltype layer with 50+ categories and corresponding symbols. I need to save this symbols with the category as name in a *.style file.

[image]

**Is there a way to batch save symbols for each category of a layer as style?**

If you have got symbols having the same name like your categories in a *.style file, it enables you to import the symbols with **Match to symbols**. The advantage in opposition to importing the whole symbology of a layer is, that only categories which truly exist are imported with match to symbols. So you get a legend which only displays present categories no empty ones.

[image]

EDIT:

Additional to J.R.'s answer a screen shot of the tools location.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an "export map style" tool that export all of the symbol to a .style file, each symbol get the category name.

After exporting you probably will need to clean the .Style using the style manager as everything will be exported (color, symbol, label....)

I think you will find the tool by going to customize then to the command tab and look for the tool category (my arcmap version is not in English so it may be named differently in yours). Also in my arcmap version the search box in the customize dialog didn't return anything but the tool exist, it's just difficult to find.

Comment: Works like a charme!

Answer (score 0):

I can offer a way around this.

If you manually generate a single layer file (using unique value options) for every category you have (it's quirk of ArcMap that you have to build it like this, rather than matching to a style) and ensure the "all other values" symbol box is unticked. You can then use this layer file in combination with the "Apply Symbology From Layer" GP tool, and only those features which appear in the target layer will be symbolised, rather than it copying the entire symbology definition and having some symbols with a zero count!

Comment: My problem is, that I have to save the symbols to a *.style to publish the symbols to others. The application of the symbols is not part of my problem.

Comment: Mike, Ah, understood! I had read the issue back-to-front.

That said my workaround would mean that you wouldn't need to use a style file though. You stated:

"The advantage in opposition to importing the whole symbology of a layer is, that only categories which truly exist are imported with match to symbols. So you get a legend which only displays present categories no empty ones"

If you use my workaround and match to the layer file, it will behave like a style file, in that it will only import the symbology that is present in the target layer.

Hope that helps.