# Getting symbology of ArcMap in QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcmap, symbology

I'm working on some projects to replicate the originals that are in ArcGis to new same projects made in QGIS (3.28).

Is it possible to have ESRI Symbols in QGIS?

I mean the selectable simbol groups in **ArcMap>Symbol>"symbol property editor"** like "ESRI default marker", "ESRI environmental & icons", "ESRI Geology", etc.

How and where I can "copy", "import" or "download" them to have in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

If you have ArcMap installed on your computer, the fonts should be even available from QGIS

1. choose Font Marker as Symbol layer type
2. select the desired ESRI Font
3. Select the symbol

and respect the licence stuff from ESRI...

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering. On my PC (were I'm working) I haven't ArcMap so, does exist a way to "draw" or create simbols like in ArcMap? Also by Plugins for example?

Comment: If you search on your terms (like "ESRI environmental & icons") you will find many free downloads.  I just went to an ESRI site for these and it said under Terms of use: "No special restrictions or limitations on using the item's content have been provided" You can do your own search on that.  You can copy them from a computer with them as well instead of going through the downloads.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [SLYR plugin from North Road](https://north-road.com/slyr/). There are a free community edition and full featured licenced edition.

While the community edition won't let you directly convert an MXD to a QGIS projet it will allow to convert .lyr or style file. (if needed you could convert all symbol from an MXD to a single style file see [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245486/batch-save-symbols-for-each-category-of-a-layer-as-style-in-arcgis/313929#313929))

As said by @eurojam ESRI font will be available only on computer with ESRI product installed, on other computer you will need to manually recreate the symbology with alternative font (or better by using SVG, you may want to look at the [QGIS Resource Sharing plugin](https://qgis-contribution.github.io/QGIS-ResourceSharing/) or at the [QGIS Style page](https://plugins.qgis.org/styles/?order_by=-upload_date&&is_gallery=true) these two are great source of symbology)

Comment: Thank you for your clear explain! I will do it by these method.